# Legacy VC++, Com based Desktop application to Modern web with microservices

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, com, microservices

I am in the process of moving my existing desktop application to web. The GUI is developed using MFC/VC++ and the buisness logic is written in COM enabled VC++ DLL. This Dll has various responsibilities. Currently this Dll is loaded as part of the desktop application memory.Now I am in the initial stage of moving this application to modern web application. Below is the thought process for design considered till now,

1. Converting monolithic business logic to micro services.
2. Deploy the micro services in a server.
3. My business logic VC++ Com layer can interface with microservices and get data.
4. Have a API gateway which can communicate to microservices and it can serve to the web client.

In this process I wanted to reuse VC++ Com business logic layer as much as possible. The current com Dll is not supporting multi threading or multi user sessions. This needs to be supported. The next thing would be reusing existing MFC GUI in web.

What are the technologies can be considered to reuse my buisness logic?

Comment: A properly coded COM object can work in a multithreading environment, although it's probably not optimal for a server. Obviously it shouldn't use any UI-related stuff. That's the whole purpose of COM threading model (STA vs MTA). As for reusing MFC GUI in the web, you should forget about that completely, it must be rewritten, and usually rethought over stateless vs stateful architecture. All this deserves much more than a question here on this site.

Comment: Maybe using DCOM would be a good way to port the business logic to a microservice. I think WCF supports DCOM. But good luck porting the MFC GUI to a web service (other than with such a crude approach like opening a RDP connection).

Comment: @SimonMourier somehow i didn't get notification for your comment. Thanks for the comment. I am looking for reusing c++ Com Dll in web server . Which technology can I use for web server? I understood reusing ui code is more cumbersome.

Comment: ATL is a good technology for web server. MFC was originally created (for UI as only desktop apps existed back then on PCs) and the  ATL was created especially for server code vs MFC which was never suited for that task. They kinda mixed the two and distribute them together but you can still use base ATL classes for server development.

Comment: @SimonMourier I got that. I wanted to know how this com Dll can be hosted in webserver so that the web client can communicate. How the web client can communicate with this com Dll?

Comment: Well, just use any Web Server running on Windows with a technology/framework that can call COM components (ie: most technologies running on Windows). In the current Microsoft world, that would be ASP.NET Core and that's what I'd choose, as .NET has a nice interop story with COM.

Answer (score 2):

For the most code-reuse I think you're on the right track.

You definitely want to separate out the business logic into it's own service and you can expose that via any communication protocol you prefer. The biggest downside to this is that every time functionality needs to be added, it needs to be added in two places, or in this case three: the business logic server, the MFC server, and the web server.

As others have pointed out, MFC was really intended for desktop applications. A "modern web application" is one that is stateless and communicates via message-passing over http(s) with the web browser being the client. There's really no re-using the MFC GUI in the web. The architectures are just too disconnected.

Having said that, and I haven't looked into it too much, but Blazor is a WASM compiler. It has limited support for the .net framework, even less so around the communication portion of it, but it *might* be able to compile your project. I'd bet against it, however.

I think you'd be better off just focusing on a decent web experience with a SPA and abandoning the MFC/Desktop portion. Maybe later you can circle back and build a GUI through MAUI or WPF that consumes the web API.